# jQuery - change font-weight of specific text with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, frontend

I have two divs with the same class name as :

```
<button>Click to change font weight.</button>

<div class="wt">Paragraph 1</p>
<div class="wt">Paragraph 2</p>
```

Using jQuery, I'm trying to change the font-weight of the div that has "Paragraph 1" as text. What would be the best way to approach this? This is what I'm trying - but it would of course set both the divs' text to bold:

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    if($(".wt").text().trim() == "Paragraph 1")
    {
        $(".wt").css("font-weight","bold" )  
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery contains() method:

```
$(".wt:contains(Paragraph 1)").css("font-weight","bold" )
```

Answer (score 1):

For your query, I would add class instead:

```
$('.wt:first').addClass('font-weight-bold');
```

If you're using bootstrap 4, it would automatically support the class. Otherwise, add this rule in your stylesheet:

```
.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

If your paragraph is not the first in the DOM Tree and looking for the text, then use contains selector as suggest in other answer:

```
$('.wt:contains("Paragraph 1")').addClass('font-weight-bold');
```

---

One last thing, I forgot about to mention that you can use toggleClass to toggle the changes upon button clicks.

```
$('.wt:first').toggleClass('font-weight-bold');
```

Comment: Both get boldened: https://jsfiddle.net/xvqc25mu/2/

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I overwhelmed that you're using $(this) selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

I've added some additional functionality so you can toggle between `font-weight`'s. It is worth noting that calling `.css('font-weight')` with jQuery will not return you string values such as `normal` or `bold`; instead calling this will retrieve numbers (`'400' === 'normal'`, `'700' === 'bold'` etc).

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  let par1 = $(".wt:contains('Paragraph 1')");

  // Toggle between font-weights
  par1.css(
    'font-weight',
    (['normal', '400'].indexOf(par1.css('font-weight')) === -1) ? 'normal' : 'bold'
  );

  // Or, uncomment and use this if you do not wish to toggle the div
  // par1.css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click to change font weight.</button>

<div class="wt">Paragraph 1</div>
<div class="wt">Paragraph 2</div>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("button").click(function(){
   $(".wt").each(function(){
     if($(this).text() == "Paragraph 1")
     $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
   });
 });
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with a textual explanation of the code snippet and explain how it answers the question